# Bulk Insert with special characters as delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to bulk insert using special characters as the field terminators.

My input file looks like this;

[image]

ASCII: 254 is a field quote and ASCII:020 is a fieldterminator.

SQL Server version is 11.0.5058.0

My code so far;

```
bulk
INSERT edMe.dbo.test
FROM 'H:\test.dat' WITH (fieldterminator = 'þþ',
                      rowterminator = '\n',
                      datafiletype = 'widechar',
                      codepage ='acp'
                      )
```

However, 0 records get inserted;

```
Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as widechar. DataFileType will be assumed to be char because the data file does not have a Unicode signature.
Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as widechar. DataFileType will be assumed to be char because the data file does not have a Unicode signature.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your file end in a newline?

Comment: It did, removed, updated question

Comment: What about if you use `fieldterminator = CHAR(254)+CHAR(254), rowterminator = 0x0a`? `codepage='raw'` may also help

Comment: Still doesn't work, sorry